# Слово "особенно" перед союзом

Tags: пунктуация

Прочитала, что запятые в этих случаях (особенно если, особенно когда) ставить не требуется, но все же хочу еще раз уточнить.

Особенно если есть конкуренты с готовыми, отработанными решениями.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятая после "особенно" вообще не нужна, не только перед "если" и "когда", это не вводное слово, а наречие.